# How to setup the jquery wysiwyg change event?

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, onchange

Has anyone successfully used the jquery plugin wysiwyg ver 0.97 to call an event handler when the contents of the edit control changes?

I'm calling wysiwyg like this

```
$("#practice_form_text .wysiwyg").wysiwyg({
    events: {
      change: function(event) {
        return alert("changed");
      }
    }
  });
```

The alert message is never displayed. Any ideas to try would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Russ

Comment: This events: {} works for keypress and click, but not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't find any method on the [documentation](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg/blob/master/README.rst) to use the **change event**, non the less, here is a useful approach:

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="wysiwyg" rows="5" cols="103"></textarea>
```

**JQUERY**

```
// initialize the wysiwyg
$("#wysiwyg").wysiwyg();

// bind the event event
$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg('document').keypress(function(e) {

    // This will cancel the keypress
    e.preventDefault();

    // alert
    alert('Keypress detected!');
});
```

And a nice demo [Fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/TsqN3/)

Comment: This example works for keypress and change, yeah, something that works.